# Windows Version

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Determine if O/S is Windows 7…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102401/determine-if-o-s-is-windows-7)
>   [How to tell if the OS is Windows XP or higher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732432/how-to-tell-if-the-os-is-windows-xp-or-higher)

Hi

How to find user windows is XP or Vista or Windows 7 ?

regards

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732432/how-to-tell-if-the-os-is-windows-xp-or-higher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look at the `Environment.OSVersion`-Property.

Answer (score 1):

See Environment.OSVersion; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.osversion%28VS.80%29.aspx